# What are the limits on CUDA printf arguments?

Tags: c++, cuda, printf

I am doing `printf` from a `__device__` function for debugging purposes. The `printf` is massive, with a multiline format string and 62 numerical values. Eh, debugging, what else can you do?

Unfortunately, the output of said `printf` is complete gibberish at the tail of the output. It feels like an uninitialized memory dump. After a day of poking around I started suspecting the `printf` and split it into 3 separate calls to `printf`, with 20-ish parameters each. And, hooray! the output made sense.

Thus the first question: is there a documented limit on the number of arguments or on the size of the output that CUDA `printf` can handle?

Now, after splitting the call into three, I have another problem: although each call to `printf` seems to lock stdout, so that output from separate threads don't interfere with each other, but that's no longer true for multiple calls. I am now getting output like this:

```
First printf from thread 0
First printf from thread 1
Second printf from thread 0
First printf from thread 2
Third printf from thread 0
...
```

Thus the second question: if CUDA `printf` indeed has limitations and massive calls have to be broken into smaller ones, is there a way to force a cohesive output, without a race?

Comment: Not directly related: `Eh, debugging, what else can you do?` [CUDA-GDB](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html) isn't an option (Windows)? `:(`

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations): "The printf() command can accept at most 32 arguments in addition to the format string. " On SO, it is preferred one question per question. The second issue presumes (I guess) that CUDA threads execute in lockstep. They don't, at least not guaranteed/not necessarily. You could enforce lockstep execution with execution barriers, I guess. That seems like a lot of baggage for debug printing.